# Get gulp watch modified file path

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I am using gulp-watch to monitor for file changes.

```
watch('public/**/*.js', function () {
    runSequence('compressjs');
});
```

How can I capture the path of modified file for custom processing use later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
watch('public/**/*.js').on('change', function (file) {
    runSequence('compressjs');
});
```

Now the file is available within the scope of the function. You can for example use `file.path` to get the path of the file that was changed.

Edit: The above solution only works with `gulp.watch`, but looking at the [code](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/blob/master/index.js) for the `gulp-watch` plugin, I think the following should work for the plugin:

```
watch('public/**/*.js', function (file) {
    runSequence('compressjs');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Your solution does work, but it only works with `gulp.watch`. How can I do it with `gulp-watch` plugin?

Comment: @user1995781, I edited the answer with the code that I think should work based on the code of the plugin.